# result array list 2 column android java

Tags: java, android

how to display 2 column lists, I have data like this, and this data is input with 1 EditText with the results:

```
56
123
54
321
55
213
45
```

I want to display it in a 2 column list with the results:

```
56 123
54 321
55 213
45
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
public class TwoColumnArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {56, 123, 54, 321, 55, 213, 45};
        printTwoColumnArray(numbers);
        
    }
    public static void printTwoColumnArray(int[] array) {
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(array.length-1==i) {
                System.out.println(array[i]);
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(array[i]+" "+array[i+1]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
56 123
54 321
55 213
45
```

**Explanation**

Basically, all we need to do is print 2 items every time we loop through the array. However, we must perform a check everytime to ensure that the item currently looping through will not throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException, as we are also attempting to print out the item after the current one.

**Sample I/O**

*Input (test case)*

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

*Output*

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9
```